# StackExchange.Redis.RedisTimeoutException - due to qs how have people solved it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, redis, .net-core, stackexchange.redis

I have some large payloads going into redis (upto 40 kb).

> StackExchange.Redis.RedisTimeoutException: Timeout performing SETEX cachekeyID (5000ms), inst: 1, qs: 11, in: 2837, serverEndpoint: servername:6380, mgr: 10 of 10 available, clientName: 419c1daaa93f, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=1,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=39,Free=32728,Min=1,Max=32767), v: 2.0.519.65453 (Please take a look at this article for some common client-side issues that can cause timeouts: https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)

How have you fixed this? By chunking the keys as suggested or by opening multiple ConnectionMultiplexers and handling the pool yourself, both are not straightforward tasks if you want to do this behind an interface which is a generic solution that is transparent to a caller?

Comment: This seems to be a networking issue more than anything else. 40KB is not "big". I mean, I guess it's somewhat larger than values one would typically store in Redis, but unless your Redis server is on dialup, it should still take virtually no time to transmit 40KB of data. Additionally, the `qs` param indicates how many requests are backed up, and that's showing 11, meaning the issue is being piled upon.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime back I have faced same issue redis timeout.
below changes solved my problem.

1. Use Linux server for Redis instead of windows server
2. Use command flag while Get and Set operation, while Get operation use
   CommandFlags.PreferSlave and while Set use
   CommandFlags.FireAndForget.
3. Change processModel as per application
   server configuration [more](https://gist.github.com/JonCole/e65411214030f0d823cb#file-threadpool-md)
4. Disable redis persistence [more description here](https://redis.io/topics/persistence)